# I want to attach a file in Xcode to an email

Tags: swift

I wrote the code as below

```
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
    {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        let fileName = "sampleText"
        let url = "textFiles/sampleText.txt"
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            mail.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "txt", fileName: fileName)
            present(mail, animated: true)
        }catch {
            print("error ...")
        }
    } else {

    }
```

I get the following error

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'

The file structure of my Xcode looks like the image below

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

How do I clear the error?

Comment: `txt` is not a MIME type. That would be `text/plain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load it like

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sampleText", withExtension: "txt") else { return }
```

> Note : folders with yellow colors `textFiles` are fake while ones with blue colors are true